# Removing Recaptcha v2 problematically after being solved

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm adding the Google Recaptcha v2 problematically to a backbone view like so:

```
// this is the callback function
var getRecaptchaResponse = function (response) {
    if (response) {
        thisView.captchaResponse = response;
        thisView.canShowContinue();
    } else {
        alert("Captcha response was incorrect");
    }
};

// render the recaptcha
var renderCaptcha = function () {
    thisView.captchaWidgetId = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-container', {
        sitekey: GlobalSettings.recaptchaKey,
        callback: getRecaptchaResponse,
        size: 'compact'
    });
};

// map the internal function to the window
// so that the callback registered in the 
// link below can be called by JSONP.
window.renderCaptcha = renderCaptcha;

// load the script
$.getScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderCaptcha&render=explicit', function () { });
```

Once the Captcha is solved successfully I want to remove it from the UI, so I'm simply removing the `div` container:

```
// if the user has solved the captcha yet, don't continue
if (!thisView.captchaResponse) {
    return;
}

// remove recpatcha
$('#recaptcha-container').remove();
```

There doesn't seem to be a [API method](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api) that Google have offered to destroy the `grecaptcha` widget properly though. Is this a problem? What's the recommended way of doing this?

The above removal of the container works in Chrome, but not in IE11. In IE11 the captcha challenge remains visible.

Comment: Did you mean programmatically?

Comment: @Ezenhis exactly. I'm looking to do `grecaptcha.remove('recaptcha-container');` or somethigng similar.

Answer (score 3):

As per reCAPTCHA's FAQ, it seems that after removing the container, you should reset the captcha object using `grecaptcha.reset(id)`

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

> I'm getting an uncaught SecurityError: blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "". What should I do?
>
> This typically occurs if the reCAPTCHA widget HTML element is
>   programmatically removed sometime after the end user clicks on the
>   checkbox. We recommend using the grecaptcha.reset() javascript
>   function to reset the reCAPTCHA widget.

Comment: I wasn't getting any error, but that does now solve the problem. After removing the container and calling reset() the verification screen now disappears. Thank you.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to keep the context of "this typically occurs [...]"  in the quote ;) Glad it helps :)

Comment: I noticed that in Chrome, the reset isn't needed, and instead throws a Javascript error, but in IE is is required. So I have a check now to see if it is IE, and only run that reset if it is.

Comment: Yea.. IE is a bit.. *special* so to say.. ;)